# strapi forgot password plugin doesn't send email

Tags: javascript, authentication, strapi, reset-password, headless-cms

I use strapi as an admin panel. When a user need to reset his password, the link forgot my password should send an email with a link to reset, but nothing happens.

I don't find any information in the strapi documentation to solve the problem. Does anyone can give me a lead to step forward on this problem? I'm stuck at 0

thank you

Comment: I'm looking into the same issue. It just logs "Error: can not connect to any SMTP server".

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck but found the answer on the Strapi forum.

At root of your project, run this command:

```
npm run strapi admin:reset-user-password --email=existing@user.com --password=NewPassword
```

(You'll need to use real values for your email and password flags)

Once you've ran that command, you’ll be prompted to input the same details again eg:

```
[? User email? existing@user.com
[? New password? [hidden]
[? Do you really want to reset this user's password? Yes
```

(These need to match the email and password you used on the previous command)

Finally you'll need to run

```
strapi build
```

Once it's rebuilt, you'll be able to start Strapi and log into the admin with you new details!

Original instructions/tread: https://forum.strapi.io/t/reset-strapi-admin/6136